# How to access widgets/views in android when multiple xml's are used in a single activity?

Tags: android, runtime-error, textview, typeface

I have made a welcome screen in my application which uses swipe gesture to switch between screens. There are total 5 xml layouts in the same welcome screen activity. My aim is to add a font(change typeface of text views) programmatically in all the 5 layouts. But the prblem is, a run time error occurs(attempt to invoke virtual object) in the text views i want to apply the typeface into. I guess this is because when we use multiple layouts, 'R.id.txtView' doesn't work (this is only my guess). If any of you knowledgeable people know the answer of my question, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the logcat along with the java code and one xml

Comment: Okay wait. let me post it

Answer (score 0):

make 1 activity and 5 fragment. Like this you can contorol all fragment and all xml.

Comment: Dmytro, the fragments won't work, because i am using horizontal swipe, and each time i swipe, a new xml appears.